# Flask Blueprint method not receiving Jinja argument

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

my Blueprint method fails as soon as I enter a parameter in the method:

```
TypeError: get_streetreport() missing 1 required positional argument: 'number'
```

Called from Jinja:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action = "{{ url_for('street_reports.get_streetreport', number=number) }}" method="post">
```

FYI, I can see the variable number is accessible on this same calling page:

```
<p>You have entered "{{ number }}" in the property name/number field on the previous page.</p>
```

This the Blueprint method which is called:

```
@street_report_blueprint.route('/street_report', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def get_streetreport(number):
    mainselection = request.form['MainlistRadios']
    return render_template('street_reports/street_report.jinja2', mainselection = mainselection)
```

If I remove the parameter from get_streetreport(), page loads fine on local host. 'number' is a string variable. Tx any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: you need to declare the parameter in the route path.

`@street_report_blueprint.route('/street_report/<number>', …)`

If `number` is expected to be an integer, it would be `.../<int:number>`

See http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/quickstart/#variable-rules

> To add variable parts to a URL you can mark these special sections as . Such a part is then passed as a keyword argument to your function. Optionally a converter can be used by specifying a rule with .

---

You need to pass the number parameter into `render_template`

`return render_template(....., number=number)`

Comment: OK I have changed last line to test this: 'return render_template('street_reports/street_report.jinja2', number = number)' but still same error message.

Comment: Thanks @Ivan My understanding was action = `"{{ url_for('street_reports.get_streetreport', number=number) }}"` is passing the argument 'number' to the get_streetreport method, and error says get_streetreport missing the argument. I assume error is not really in the render_template line, but I am beginner at Flask. I would include further info if I knew what is needed. Re negative votes, I have made effort to search Google and SO for answers but not found. Equally, I have titled it as best I can.

Comment: Ps I think the downvote is unwarranted. +1 for you. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks @Ivan , this works now, I should have thought to check jinja pocoo perhaps! but might not have clicked anyway without you telling me. This tells me my approach wrong anyway now, i thought I could pass a complete object to the Flask blueprint method in the method parameter, then pass this object to the webpage with render_template, but this is clearly not practical. Maybe I can just put the object inside the form somehow and use form.request to pass whole object, bit of a hack, but this is demo app and time pressed, will see.

Comment: You can also check out `request.values` to receive the form query/post data. http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#incoming-request-data